Modify CameraSensor zoom from gazebo C++ plugin
I want to create a gazebo Garden plugin that will allow me to modify camera sensor zoom (near, far and HFOV). For this I have simple camera model file:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <model name="testcam">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <link name="camera_link">
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <sensor name="camera_sensor" type="camera">
        <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
            <width>320</width>
            <height>240</height>
          </image>
          <clip>
            <near>0.1</near>
            <far>100</far>
          </clip>
          <lens>
            <type>gnomonical</type>
            <scale_to_hfov>true</scale_to_hfov>
            <cutoff_angle>1.5707</cutoff_angle>
            <env_texture_size>512</env_texture_size>
          </lens>
        </camera>
        <always_on>1</always_on>
        <update_rate>30</update_rate>
        <topic>/testCameraTopic</topic>
        <plugin name="TestCamera::Zoomable" filename="libTestCamera"></plugin>
      </sensor>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>

That camera is added to the world.sdf file that is used when Gazebo is launched. The camera is visible in the GazeboGUI.
In the plugin, the main class looks like follows:
namespace TestCamera
{
using namespace gz;
using namespace sim;
class Zoomable : public gz::sim::System,
    public gz::sim::ISystemConfigure,
    public gz::sim::ISystemUpdate
{
public:
    Zoomable(){};
    ~Zoomable() override {};

    void Configure(
        const Entity & _entity,
        const std::shared_ptr<const sdf::Element> & _sdf,
        EntityComponentManager & _ecm,
        EventManager & _eventMgr) override;

    void Update(const UpdateInfo & _info, EntityComponentManager & _ecm) override;
};
}

GZ_ADD_PLUGIN(
    TestCamera::FurgonCamera,
    gz::sim::System,
    TestCamera::FurgonCamera::ISystemConfigure,
    TestCamera::FurgonCamera::ISystemUpdate)

The plugin loads and both Configure and Update methods are called during work of Gazebo. The idea I have right now, is to create instance of gz::sensors::CameraSensor class, so that I will be able to get the rendering::CameraPtr using RenderingCamera() method and that will let me change the HFOV using SetHFOV method and near/far using SetNearClipPlane/SetFarClipPlane methods of the gz::rendering::Camera class.
I just can't find a way to connect/attach the gz::sensors::CameraSensor class with the instance of camera sensor described in the sdf file ("camera_sensor"). Looks that none of the parameters I get in the Zoomable::Configure(...) method is suitable for that.
How this can be achieved?
Is there other approach to do it?
I'm using Gazebo Garden Sim version 7.7.0.
